# Database Structure to store multiple inheritance classes

Tags: nhibernate, database-design, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have two distinct (no inheritance) interfaces:
`IInvestable` and `IPricable` 
and two classes: 
`IndexClass` and `FundClass`
that are stored in seperate tables in my DB.

`IndexClass` is `IPriceable`
`FundClass` is `IPriceable` and `IInvestable`.

I need a table to store prices against an `IndexClass` and a `FundClass`
I need a table to store that `FundClasses` are invested in.

One way might be to have two tables: `Pricable` and `Investable` which just have an ID column. 
Then have a foreign key on `IndexClass`: `PricableID`
Also have two foreign keys on `FundClass`: `PricableID` and `InvestableID`.

Then my Prices simply link to the `PricableID` and my Investments simply link to the `InvestmentID` as these will be unique.

Alternativly I could have `FundClassID` and `IndexClassID` columns on the Price table but this doesn't seem scalable and seems like it'll be difficult to work with.

Then let NHibernate figure it out - which I'm still not 100% certain it'll like!

I can't really find anything on the internet with recommendations for storing Multiple Inheritance and wondered if anyone had any ideas for this or if they've tackled something similar in the past?

Thanks

Stu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up with the following structure:

FundClass: FundClassID (etc)
FundClassReturn:FundClassID, ReturnID
IndexClass: IndexClassID (etc)
IndexClassReturn: IndexClassID, ReturnID
Return: ReturnID (etc)

then I simply sort this in the NHibernate mapping file. I was trying to be too old fashioned and making it too DB centric. Everything I have is written to interfaces anyway so I simply query the interfaces and let NHibernate handle the rest with intrisic polymorphism. Works like a charm!

Thanks for your help though - it's provoked the thoughts for the end solution.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would favor composition over inheritance.  The classes could be PriceInfo and InvestmentInfo, for example, and your IInvestable and IPricable interfaces would include properties of those types.

Edit: The resulting database schema would look something like this:

```
PriceInfo
---------
PriceInfoId
[Other Stuff]

InvestmentInfo
--------------
InvestmentInfoId
[Other Stuff]

IndexClass
---------
IndexClassId
PriceInfoId
[Other Stuff]

FundClass
---------
FundClassId
PriceInfoId
InvestmentInfoId
[Other Stuff]
```

Comment: I'm still confused as to how I would store this in the DB as I still need some way of linking prices to a particular entity even if there is a FundClass of ID 10 and an IndexClass of ID 10, what structure should I use?

Comment: Foreign keys.  You'll still have FundClass and IndexClass classes.  I'm assuming that NHibernate would translate the PriceInfo and InvestmentInfo properties of both to foreign keys.  See my edit for what the DB schema would look like.