# Interfaces and multiplicity contraint violation on EF 4.1 Code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to define a supply chain with Suppliers, Dealers and Retailers. This entities are bound by a Contract class that also defines the ProductLine and the Products they will work with.
For a given ProductLine, there will be a contract between a Supplier (the sole owner of that ProductLine) and a Dealer, and then another contract between this Dealer and a Retailer.

The problem is that there's also a contract between two dealers so I tried creating two interfaces (ISeller and IBuyer). Supplier implements ISeller, Retailer implements IBuyer and Dealer implements both interfaces:

```
public class Supplier : ISeller
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
}

public class Dealer : ISeller, IBuyer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
}

public class Retailer : IBuyer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
}
```

The Contract then bounds a ISeller to a IBuyer, like this:

```
public class Contract
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ISeller Seller { get; set; }
    public virtual IBuyer Buyer { get; set; }
}
```

Creating contracts between Supplier/Dealer or Dealer/Retailer works as intended, but I get a '**Multiplicity constraint violated**' when trying to create a Dealer/Dealer contract.

Comment: Can you look at the database schema that was generated from your class design?  That might reveal why it's having trouble with that relationship.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention that the layout for the Contract table is a bit odd: 
Id | Supplier_Id | Dealer_Id | Retailer_Id
This way it's clear that I cannot have two Dealers in the same contract. Maybe I should use custom mapping to help EF understand what I'm trying to do. Problem is I'm not fluent on Fluent API. :)

Comment: Well, that's your problem.  I don't know much yet about EF Code First, though, so this is all the help I personally can give.

Comment: Can you show exactly the code which throws this error? Also be aware that for EF the `Seller` and `Buyer` properties in the `Contract` class don't exist because they are interfaces and not entities. So they are *not* navigation properties.

Comment: I can't paste code in comments so I'll just explain the proccess: create a dealer, create another dealer, create a contract and set it's Seller property to dealer1 and it's buyer property to dealer2, add this 3 entities to the context and save it: "Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Dealer_Contracts_Source' of the relationship 'ContractTest.Model.Dealer_Contracts' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1."

Comment: You can edit your question ("edit" link below question) to show such details. Are the two properties in `Contract` really the interfaces and not a concrete type like `Dealer`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the problem with this code is the interfaces. As Slauma said in the comments, the interface members of Contract class are not mapped at all since EF does not know, for example, which entities - Supplier, Dealer or both - map to Seller member.

From the other direction we have that each of the supply chain participants have multiple contracts. This results in Supplier_id, Dealer_id, Reseller_id columns in Contracts table. From EF perspective, Supplier and Dealer have nothing in common, neither do Retailer and Dealer.

What you need to do is to have entity inheritance. Dealer can be both seller and buyer though so you cannot have 2 separate classes as C# does not allow multiple inheritance. Define ContractParticipant base entity and have Supplier, Dealer and Retailer inherit from it. Then your data model would look something like:

```cs
public abstract class ContractParticipant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Seller")]
    public virtual ICollection<Contract> SellerContracts { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Buyer")]
    public virtual ICollection<Contract> BuyerContracts { get; set; }
}

public class Supplier : ContractParticipant
{
    <...other properties here...>
}

public class Dealer : ContractParticipant
{
    <...other properties here...>
}

public class Retailer : ContractParticipant
{
    <...other properties here...>
}

public class Contract
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ContractParticipant Seller { get; set; }
    public virtual ContractParticipant Buyer { get; set; }
}
```

This model should generate database structure that would support your scenario without any other configuration. However it would also allow contracts between any types of participants but If you try to map multiple inheritance in data model you would end up with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493088/database-structure-to-store-multiple-inheritance-classes) - consider if you want to complicate your data model to preserve these constraints.

Comment: +1: This looks good! (One point: I think you meant the `[InverseProperty(...)]` attribute and not `[ForeignKey(...)]`.)

Comment: Many thanks! It seems like we have a winner here. And I can use a custom entity validation to inhibit contracts being made between supplier/supplier and retailer/retailer so this won't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Trying using this one :

```
public class Contract
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Seller Sellers { get; set; }
    public virtual Buyer Buyers { get; set; }
}
```